# Problema con una consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema de como formular una consulta para obtener 
los siguiente: tengo una tabla llamada TBL_BIT_TIPO_INGRESO donde almaceno 
los tipos de ingresos económicos al registrar unos estudiantes. Se supone 
que por default se guarda en el campo tipo_ingreso un texto que dice "FAMILIA" y después se puede agregar otro registro por si el alumno obtiene otro tipo de 
ingreso, por ejemplo "PROPIOS" o "PROGRAMA_GOBIERNO".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el sistema que hice de ejemplo tiene una falla y cuando almacena un 
alumno nuevo no guarda el registro con el texto default que mencione anteriormente pero si guarda los demás registros por si se registra otro tipo 
de ingreso. Quiero hacer un query para obtener esos estudiantes que no tienen
registros con el texto "FAMILIA" en el campo tipo_ingreso. En el ejemplo de la imágen saldrian A4A12, A3B07, A3B20 y A7C25 pero no consigo hacerlo, ¿me pueden explicar?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la query que has intentado y falla? Si la compartes, podríamos ayudarte a encontrar posibles errores y mejoras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indica en tu consulta que deseas mostrar todas las filas de datos donde el tipo de ingreso sea diferente de FAMILIA, eso lo consigues con el operador !=

`SELECT * FROM TBL_BIT_TIPO_INGRESO WHERE tipo_ingreso!='FAMILIA'`

Comment: Ya resolví ese problema, igual no describí bien como era en verdad la bronca xD pero ya esta gracias

Answer (score -1):

Para comparaciones de texto es mejor usar LIKE, en este caso puedes usar NOT LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_BIT_TIPO_INGRESO WHERE tipo_ingreso NOT LIKE 'FAMILIA'
```